# Can I pass a keystroke from command line into the gui

Tags: 12.04, startup, gui, remote

I am trying out different options for remote desktop control, and at the moment Slashtop Streamer seems promising due to the speed, and some other things regarding the way it handles multiple screens.

My problem is that I would like to use wake-on-LAN to boot my Ubuntu desktop, so as to not waste a lot of power having the computer run all day while I'm at school or the like, so the Slashtop client needs to start on login. This is done with the startup applications system in Ubuntu, but Slashtop requires me to press the enter key in order to log in.

So, is it possible to add something to the command line in startup apps, that tell the computer to pass this enter keystroke into the active window on the desktop?

I realise that this is a somewhat narrow question, and I a similar one being posted a while back that got shut down due to it's less than broad nature, but I hope to get an answer none the less.

Comment: Why you don't configure Ubuntu to log into a determinate account by default?

Comment: Can we have the command? Oh and`\n` is considered an enter while coding.

Comment: When you say *log in* are you talking about an Ubuntu user or a Slashtop procedure?

Comment: Try the `xdotool` utility. I have not been able to make it fully work, so I'm not adding it as an answer. You'd need to use the functions `search`, `windowfocus`, and `key`.

Comment: I see I should have been more specific (and thanks for the answers!).

In Ubuntu's Startup Applications I have added the entry "Slashtop" which executes this command: "python /opt/splashtop-streamer/streamer.pyc" 
This launches a promt there my credentials for loging on to Slashtop's central servers are already filled in (email and password). The problem is that the promt also needs me to hit a confirm button. When I am at the computer I do this by pressing enter, but when I am trying to remote control the computer I can not physically press any keys.

Comment: I have found a couple of things now. First of all, the promt (Splashtop login on the main computer) needs a mousepress on the confirm button. Using the tool Paddy Landau pointed me to I have managed to place the window in one spot every time the command is used: "python /opt/splashtop-streamer/streamer.pyc & xdotool sleep 1 getactivewindow windowmove 0 0". My problem now is that I do not know how the xdotool maps the screen, as the 0 0 placement is not perfectly in the upper left corner (how do I upload a screenshot so that you can see what I am talking about?).

Comment: I believe I have the answer now: "python /opt/splashtop-streamer/streamer.pyc & xdotool sleep 1 getactivewindow windowmove 0 0 mousemove 280 200 sleep 1 click 1". Will test now.

Answer (score 0):

Jonas, this is exactly what i needed since my laptop screen is broken and i'm converting it into a server. I tried the code in your last post but it didn't do the job completely. It opened the splashtop window but the click didn't happen, the cursor remained in its default position. Did you have any luck?

Comment: I am afraid it did not work the way I intended it to. I have abandoned the whole idea as it seems the splashtop login window is placed some kind of strange way in relation to the mouse pointers initial placement on the desktop (I can't figure out this relationship, so to me the placement of the login seems random). I am sorry I can not help you. But it took me some time to figure out the xdotool. I used the man-page (all the way to the end of it there are some examples) but it is slightly messy regarding structure.

Comment: I found a solution and its working. I figured that the command you mentioned above ("python /opt/splashtop-streamer/streamer.pyc & xdotool sleep 1 getactivewindow windowmove 0 0 mousemove 280 200 sleep 1 click 1")  does run but we need to add a delay before the click so i added the following link before click:

X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=60

you can change the delay to something like 15 or 20 sec and it works fine.